# Why is Aurora Firefox continually throwing sync errors?

Tags: firefox, firefox-sync

Firefox keeps giving me this error:

> Sync encountered an error while synchronising: Unknown error. Sync will automatically retry this action.

I am able to log in, but some minutes later... bam! the same error, again and again.

Could it be my password? Too long? Unsupported weird characters?

Running current version: Aurora 29.0a2 (2014-03-03)